# How could I make an earth sized planet with 3 moons work?

Tags: science-fiction, earth-like, moons

Im world building an earth sized planet with 3 moons. These three moons are symbolic in my world with many religions on this world celebrating the number 3 and saying the best things come in 3. I was thinking that each of the moons could be 1/3 the mass of our moon  and id want them to be able to be seen at the same time at night or at least occasionally at the same time. but im not really good at math or astrophysics for that matter and im unsure what kind of orbit or size would be needed for them to not crash into each other.

How do I make it work without them crashing into each other and what effects would I need to consider for my world building?

Comment: Please check the accepted answer to the question: even though the question is different, that answer explains how your system can work.